# Somar linhas com o mesmo ano

Tags: mysql

Problema:-Somar as linhas que têm anos iguais através de comando no mysql.

Query que estou utilizando:

```
SELECT produtividade, ano
FROM area_e_producao_05_15
INNER JOIN dados_cidades
ON edr_id={$edr['edr_id']}
WHERE area_e_producao_05_15.id_municipio=dados_cidades.dados_cidades_id AND Ano BETWEEN {$ano} and {$ano2} Order By Ano
```

O meu resultado foi:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse caso o resultado foi pouco,mas em alguns casos são gerados muitos anos iguais.
Existe alguma forma de somar essas produtividades e apresentar uma linha com cada ano?
Exemplo da foto o resultado esperado é:

produtividade|Ano
50           |2010
50           |2011

Comment: usa um group by ano

Comment: Você pode usar o GROUP BY;

Comment: SELECT SUM(produtividade) AS produtividade, ano ....... WHERE .... GROUP BY ano;

Comment: Group By ele não realiza a soma.@ramaral mas essa é uma outra query?ou está dizendo para juntar a que está ali?

Comment: Essa é a sua query com SUM e GROUP BY acrescentados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
 SELECT sum(produtividade), ano
   FROM area_e_producao_05_15
  INNER JOIN dados_cidades
     ON edr_id={$edr['edr_id']}
  WHERE area_e_producao_05_15.id_municipio=dados_cidades.dados_cidades_id 
    AND Ano BETWEEN {$ano} and {$ano2} 
  GROUP BY ano
  ORDER BY ano
```

Comment: ,Funcionou.Obrigado